# Write External Storage in AndroidTest

Tags: java, android, testing, android-permissions, android-external-storage

I wanted to write an `AndroidTest` for an App which involves writing to external storage but somehow I am not able to make it work. (Testing on several devices like Pixel2, Lg G6, Huawai P8)

So I simplified everything just to test if writing to external storage is possible at all. I experimented with [GrantPermissionRule](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/test/rule/GrantPermissionRule.html) as well as writing my on Granter with no success at all.

I probably ended up doing way too much unnecessary stuff, so here is what I have done:

1. Create new Project with no Activity in `AndroidStudio`
2. added permission to Manifest
3. added `AndroidManifest` with `uses-permission` tag
4. Wrote my own `PermissionRequester`
5. Wrote test to try to add a Folder in /sdcard/Download and delete it

Following are snippets referenced by numbered List above

2.

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.company.android.testpermissions">
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="com.company.TestPermissions"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" />
</manifest>
```

3.

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.company.android.testpermissions.test">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

</manifest>
```

Also tried

```
<manifest package="com.company.android.testpermissions">...
```

omitting the 'test' postfix

4.

```
public class MyPermissionRequester {

    public static final String TAG = MyPermissionRequester.class.getSimpleName();

    public static void request(String... permissions) {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            UiAutomation auto = InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation().getUiAutomation();
            String cmd = "pm grant " + InstrumentationRegistry.getTargetContext().getPackageName() + " %1$s";
            String cmdTest = "pm grant " + InstrumentationRegistry.getContext().getPackageName() + " %1$s";
            String currCmd;
            for (String perm : permissions) {
                execute(String.format(cmd, perm), auto);
                execute(String.format(cmdTest, perm), auto);
            }
        }
        GrantPermissionRule.grant(permissions);
    }

    private static void execute(String currCmd, UiAutomation auto){
        Log.d(TAG, "exec cmd: " + currCmd);
        auto.executeShellCommand(currCmd);
    }
}
```

5.

```
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4.class)
public class ExampleInstrumentedTest {
    @Test
    public void sdcardTest(){

        //check sdcard availability 
        Assert.assertEquals("Media is not mounted!", Environment.getExternalStorageState(), Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED);
       //get and check Permissions
MyPermissionRequester.request(Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
        int grantResult = ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(InstrumentationRegistry.getTargetContext(), Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
        Assert.assertEquals(PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED, grantResult);
        grantResult = ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(InstrumentationRegistry.getContext(), Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
        Assert.assertEquals(PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED, grantResult);

        //finally try to create folder
        File f = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS), "CompanyTest");
        if (!f.exists()){
            boolean mkdir = f.mkdirs();
            Assert.assertTrue("Folder '"+f.getAbsolutePath() + "' not Present!", mkdir);
        }
        boolean delete = f.delete();
        Assert.assertTrue("Folder '"+f.getAbsolutePath() + "' is Present!", delete);
    }
}
```

The result of the Test is:

> junit.framework.AssertionFailedError: Folder
>   ' /storage/emulated/0/Download/CompanyTest' not Present! at
>
> junit.framework.Assert.fail(Assert.java:50) at
>
> junit.framework.Assert.assertTrue(Assert.java:20) at
>
> com.company.android.testpermissions.ExampleInstrumentedTest.sdcardTest(ExampleInstrumentedTest.java:69)
>
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) at
>   ...
>   (omitted rest coming from the TestRunner)

What am I missing here or doing wrong?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

After a lot of pain trying stuff which doesn't work I finally got the solution:

Google's claims that

```
if your application already requests write access, it will automatically get read access as well.
```

https://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-4.1.html#Permissions

or in WriteExternalStorage docs:

```
Note: If your app uses the WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission, then it implicitly has permission to read the external storage as well.
```

https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/files.html#WriteExternalStorage

Or in manifest Permissions:

```
Any app that declares the WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission is implicitly granted this permission.
```

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE

except it doesn't!

If I explicitly add `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` to my manifest as well as requesting it on Runtime, it works like I was used to.

So 3. must add

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.company.android.testpermissions.test">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
</manifest>
```

and the Test should look like this:

```
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4.class)
public class ExampleInstrumentedTest {
    @Test
    public void sdcardTest(){

        //check sdcard availability 
        Assert.assertEquals("Media is not mounted!", Environment.getExternalStorageState(), Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED);
       //get and check Permissions
MyPermissionRequester.request(Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
        int grantResult = ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(InstrumentationRegistry.getTargetContext(), Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
        Assert.assertEquals(PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED, grantResult);
        grantResult = ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(InstrumentationRegistry.getContext(), Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
        Assert.assertEquals(PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED, grantResult);

        //finally try to create folder
        File f = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS), "CompanyTest");
        if (!f.exists()){
            boolean mkdir = f.mkdirs();
            Assert.assertTrue("Folder '"+f.getAbsolutePath() + "' not Present!", mkdir);
        }
        boolean delete = f.delete();
        Assert.assertTrue("Folder '"+f.getAbsolutePath() + "' is Present!", delete);
    }
}
```

and everything works.

Only question which is left is if/why this is intended behavior since Android 8.1

Comment: What do you mean why is this the intended behavior since Android 8.1? This has been required since Android 6.0+

Comment: @cjnash Do you mean that it has been required to also ask for `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` if you already have granted `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` since Android 6? Do you have a official source stating that? I mean I provided at least 2 examples where the docs tell you that `READ` is granted implicitly if you have `WRITE`

Comment: The only thing I can think of is that in both the examples that you cited, they seem to be referencing older versions of Android (it looks like they are referencing around Android 4.1). Here is a link explicitly stating that the user must explicitly approve each permission that doesn't fall within the "sandbox" of the application after Android 6.0: https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html

Comment: Also, they explicitly state in the link I provided above that you HAVE to include both `READ` and `WRITE` in your manifest. Then you can use run time permissions and that will cover both, but only if you included both in your manifest. (under the "Handle the permissions request response" section)

Comment: I think a simple `@Rule
    public GrantPermissionRule mRuntimePermissionRule = GrantPermissionRule
            .grant(Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);` should also work instead of your custom `MyPermissionRequester`. It's working for me at least.

Answer (score 2):

Like I stated in my comments,

The only thing I can think of is that in both the examples that you cited, they seem to be referencing older versions of Android (it looks like they are referencing around Android 4.1). Here is a link explicitly stating that the user must explicitly approve each permission that doesn't fall within the "sandbox" of the application after Android 6.0:

https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html

Also, they explicitly state in the link I provided above that you HAVE to include both READ and WRITE in your manifest. Then you can use run time permissions and that will cover both, but only if you included both in your manifest. (under the "Handle the permissions request response" section)

Comment: But my app which is targeting Andoidoir 6.0 does not have to take the `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission at the runtime. Only adding the `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` in the manifest and taking the `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` during runtime is enough for my app to be granted permission. And also as stated in the docs https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE it is not necessary to take `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission when you have been granted `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission.

Comment: Yup, at runtime you only have to grant one, as long as it is targeted at `EXTERNAL_STORAGE` so either `READ` or `WRITE` will suffice.

Answer (score 2):

Since Android 6.0, you need to grant the runtime permission manually for running androidTest

`adb shell pm grant <pkg_name> android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
adb shell pm grant <pkg_name> android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`

You can verify the permissions by

`adb shell dumpsys package <pkg_name>`

The AndroidManifest.xml only request for those permissions, but not granted by default when install the androidTest APK.